# Undefined method in model, but other method works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller call a model for a user password reset flow. It calls two methods:

controller

```
Password.new(@user)
  .save_token_and_expiry
  .email_reset
```

model

```
module ModuleName
  class Password

    attr_accessor :token, :user

    def initialize(user)
      @token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(ModuleName.configuration.reset_token_length, false)
      @user = user
    end

    def save_token_and_expiry
      User.find_by_email(@user['email'])
        .update_attributes(password_reset_token: @token, password_token_expiry: ModuleName.configuration.password_token_expiry)
    end

    def email_reset
      PasswordResetMailer.password_reset(@user, @token).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

output

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email_reset' for true:TrueClass):
```

The first of which successfully executes, but it fails on the second.

Why is the second method returning an error?

Comment: You are returning `User` object and trying to run `Password` method on that object which won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `save_token_and_expiry` method returns `true`, on which you try to call `email_reset` method, which obviously fails. If you want to allow chaining like this, you can make `save_token_and_expiry` method return `Password` instance which it was called on:

```
def save_token_and_expiry
  User.find_by_email(@user['email'])
      .update_attributes(password_reset_token: @token, password_token_expiry: ModuleName.configuration.password_token_expiry)
  self
end
```

Comment: Ah, this make sense! Outside the scope of the question, but it feels like the way I wrote it might not be the best idea since the method calls are now order dependent. Is there perhaps a better way to make this call?

Comment: You can set `password` local variable and simply call these methods in separate expressions, which I would probably advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Rails** is not so friendly for chaining calls. `save_token_and_expiry` returns you the result of last called action in it (`update_attributes`) and `update_attributes` doesn't return you the target it was called on, but just plain true/false. That's why you have such error. If you want to fix it you can rewrite your `save_token_and_expiry` method as:

```
def save_token_and_expiry
  User.find_by_email(@user['email']).update_attributes(password_reset_token: @token, password_token_expiry: ModuleName.configuration.password_token_expiry)
  self
end
```

Comment: I don't agree with you that Rails is not friendly in this respect. The return value `true`/`false` tells whether the update succeeded or not, and is much more useful than having the record returned. Whenever you want the record, you can easily access it, just like you suggested. Or, having the record returned in case of success, and `nil` otherwise, might be more useful.

Comment: @sawa We speak about comparison. In comparison with jQuery it's not user friendly for chaining. I don't think it's too bad, I just think about it as a fact

Comment: I have to agree with @sawa on this. `rails` is actually extremely call chain friendly (think about QueryMethods you can say `where().where().order().limit().where()`). In the case of this post it has nothing to do with rails but the OPs code which is not chain friendly.

Comment: @engineersmnky What do you mean under abbreviation 'OPs'?

Comment: **O**riginal **P**oster ( the gender neutral person that originally posed the question). Since this module is not a rails module but rather a module written by the person posing the question it is not rails that is unfriendly in this manner but rather the OP's code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can change controller code:

```
@data = Password.new(@user)
@data.save_token_and_expiry
@data.email_reset
```